# Delete duplicate records leaving only the latest one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in MSSQL called `answers` that looks like:

```
ID Answer Country_ID Question_ID Updated
1  ans1    15          20        2018-10-14 13:17:02.680
2  ans2    15          20        2018-11-19 13:17:02.680
3  ans0    15          20        2018-11-20 13:17:02.680
4  ans5    15          22        2018-10-14 13:17:02.680
```

I need to do the following:

- Copy from table answers the duplicated records as per Question_ID for a given Country ID  to the `answersArchive` table and remove them from `answers`

I realize that as a result I need 2 queries for that. Currently, I wanted to just query the most recent answers (having max(Updated) value), but somehow the result of the query is incorrect:

```
select *
from answers a
inner join (
    select Question_ID, max(Updated) as MaxDate
    from answers
    WHERE Country_ID = 15
    group by Question_ID
) a2 on a.Question_ID = a2.Question_ID and a.Updated = a2.MaxDate
where a.Country_ID = 15
order by a.Question_ID;
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Count` with `partition by` to find and insert the duplicate records into `answersArchive` table like following.

**1- Find Duplicate and Insert into** `answersArchive` **table**

```
--copy the duplicate records
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                answer, 
                country_id, 
                question_id, 
                updated, 
                Count(*) 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY question_id ) ct 
         FROM   answers 
         WHERE  country_id = 15) 
INSERT INTO answersarchive 
SELECT id, 
       answer, 
       country_id, 
       question_id, 
       updated 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  ct > 1 --Give you duplicate records
```

**2- Delete all duplicates except the latest one.**

You can use `CTE` to delete the records. To find the duplicate records you can use   `ROW_NUMBER()` with  `PARTITION BY  question_id` like following query.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                answer, 
                country_id, 
                question_id, 
                updated, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY question_id 
                    ORDER BY updated DESC) RN 
         FROM   answers 
         WHERE  country_id = 15) 

DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE  rn > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

use `row_number()` analytic function

```
 with cte as
(
 select t.*,row_number()over(partition by Question_ID order by Updated desc) rn
 from answers t
 where country_id=15
) delete from cte where rn<>1
```

--- you could use country filter in inside or outside the cte